# getopt multiple line statements while parsing arguments

Tags: bash, getopt, getopts

Having a bit of trouble here. 
I haven't had to do long options ever, so I am trying getopt rather than getopts.

For some reason it keeps stating `shift` as an unrecognized token. 
Any reason why? 
Also is this a proper implementation for getopt? Or is there a better method for this?

BASH SCRIPT BELOW:

```
FLAGS=$(getopt --long "help,user:" --name $PROGNAME -- "$@")
echo $FLAGS
eval set -- "$FLAGS"

while true; do
  case $1 in
    --help)
        usage()
        shift
        ;;
    *)
      shift
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
  shift
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In Bash you don't call functions with brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30712761/96588) - `usage()` should instead be `usage`.